Shadcn: No import alias found in your tsconfig.json file
I'm following the Shadcn docs to set up vite react app project, but when I run the following command:
npx shadcn@latest init
I get the error:

No import alias found in your tsconfig.json file.
Visit https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/vite to learn how to set an import alias.

I've set up my tsconfig.json file according to the Shadcn setup docs, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. How do I fix this error?

I found a fix in a corresponding Github issue. You just have to add ./ in front of src in your tsconfig.json file, like so:
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*"]
},


I am using javascript react. but I am still getting this error. how to fix this?

Astro Developers
In your tsconfig.json file, add the following:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
    // ...
  }
}

Source: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/astro
